# Spinner moves ScrollView downwards instead of opening upwards

Tags: android, scrollview, spinner, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I am trying to redesign an existing application for Android L. Unfortunately many components from the support or design libraries not really look like those in Google´s Material Design Guideline. However, one problem I faced is when adding a Spinner to a ScrollView.

When clicking the spinner near the edge of the screen, instead of opening upwards it "scrolls" down. It actually just pushs downwards which doesn´t look smooth. But this does not happen if the keyboard is opened (on the extern mobile). With the keyboard opened it adapts perfectly to the remaining space above the keyboard even with scrolling.

Spinner:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        />
```

So now my question: Is there a possibility to fix this? Like telling the spinner to orientate at the real visible screen and its relative position?

And by the way, if there´s someone who knows how to create the real material style spinner like [this one from Google´s Material Design Guideline](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B3321sZLoP_HTS1LdnhrTl9TRzg/components-buttons-otherbuttons-060203_MobileDropdowns_xhdpi_006.webm)

it would be even nicer than the standard spinner. My own approach would be to search the dataset for the selected item and set an offset of the height of one item multiplied by the position in the dataset, so the dropdown overlaps at the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `spinnerMode` attribute.

For getting the material themed spinner (simple menu), you can use [Carbon library](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon#samples).

Comment: Did not fix the problem. My assumption is that pushs down the screen because the scrollView is "bigger" than the screen.